# PostgreSQL loop through subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to loop through the results of a select subquery and use them yo fetch data off of another table:

```
SELECT alias, profile_picture 
FROM public.profile 
where user_id = (
    SELECT friend_user_id 
    FROM public.friends 
    where user_id = 1059948007363671)::text
```

obviously this query returns:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

What would be the best way to loop through the subquery results and assign it to a temporary variable that pubic.profile could use to fetch the respective profile info?

Comment: SELECT alias, profile_picture 
FROM public.profile  JOIN public.friends on profile.user_id=friends.friend_user_id WHERE friends.user_id = 1059948007363671

Comment: yea that did the trick =) thanks. I cant vote for your answer since its a comment. maybe you wanna re-post it as a questiion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT alias, profile_picture 
FROM public.profile 
JOIN public.friends 
ON profile.user_id=friends.friend_user_id 
WHERE friends.user_id = 1059948007363671
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `in` instead of `=`:

```
WHERE user_id IN 
    (
    SELECT friend_user_id::text
    FROM public.friends 
    WHERE user_id = 1059948007363671
    )
```